# what is the regex expression for the string

Tags: java, regex

I have some string as follows:

```
String str = "Data[tableName=hello,schemaName=test,columns=[column[name=h1,key=true],column[name=h2,keys=false]]]";
```

How to divide the string using regex like (),(),() to get:

1. tableName=hello
2. schemaName=test
3. columns=[column[name=h1,key=true],column[name=h2,keys=false]]

the columns are consists with column which can appear at least once.

Comment: Let me guess - Java?

Comment: Well, OP question history points at Python, but the `String` points to other langs.... Unclear.

Comment: Using regex on nested structures is not the best idea.

Comment: right, I missed that... I always lose at this game! :-(

Comment: I am using java. And what @Rawing said should be right.

Comment: Why use regex when you can have it readable? You can perfectly use onboard java tools for this. String#indexof, String#substring ...

Comment: Are `Data[` at the start and `]` at the end fixed? Or is that part dynamic?

Comment: If these can be removed with `input.replaceAll("^[^\\]\\[]+\\[|\\]$","")` I have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Data[` and last `]` are more or less fixed (say, `Data` is a variable), we may use a `replaceAll("^[^\\]\\[]+\\[|\\]$","")` to remove these values (all that is not `[` and `]` with a `[` after at the start and a `]` at the end), and parse the rest with the following method:

```
public static List<String> splitWithCommaOutsideBrackets(String input) {
    int BracketCount = 0;
    int start = 0;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        switch(input.charAt(i)) {
        case ',':
            if(BracketCount == 0) {
                result.add(input.substring(start, i).trim());// Trims the item!
                start = i+1;
            }
            break;
        case '[':
            BracketCount++;
            break;
        case ']':
            BracketCount--;
            if(BracketCount < 0) 
                return result; // The BracketCount shows the [ and ] number is unbalanced
            break;
        }
    }
    if (BracketCount > 0)
        return result; // Missing closing ]
    result.add(input.substring(start).trim()); // Trims the item!
    return result;
}
```

and use it as

```
String input = "Data[tableName=hello,schemaName=test,columns=[column[name=h1,key=true],column[name=h2,keys=false]]]";
List<String> res = splitWithCommaOutsideBrackets(input.replaceAll("^[^\\]\\[]+\\[|\\]$",""));
for (String t: res) {
    System.out.println(t); // Printing the results
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/77IJyK).

Comment: The answer is so detailed,universal and really works well. It can adapt to various situation. The function "splitWithCommaOutsideBrackets" do express what I want to tell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your description should be more clear.
Assume that the String looks like "Data[*,*,*]", you can get the content inside "Data[]" by regex expression. Now you have "*,*,*", String.split() is a good idea.

Sample code:

```
String str = "Data[tableName=hello,schemaName=test,columns=[column[name=h1,key=true]]]";
String regex = "^Data\\[(.+)\\]$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        String content = m.group(1);
        String[] split = content.split(",", 3);
        String tableName = split[0];
        String schemaName = split[1];
        String columns = split[2];
        System.out.println(tableName);
        System.out.println(schemaName);
        System.out.println(columns);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
tableName=hello
schemaName=test
columns=[column[name=h1,key=true],column[name=h2,keys=false]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think Wiktor Stribiżew's answer is more universal which can adapt to random number of columns and the columns can appear in any order in the String.

Comment: Once another string with something like `columns=[column[name=h1,key=true]]` that comes as the first argument, this approach will fail.